# Adding line breaks to strings that go into the clipboard

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following function in AutoHotkey that attaches the strings `Left` and `Right` as a prefix and suffix to a given text string that is pre-selected on a text file:

```
TagWrapper(Left, Right)
{
  ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
  Clipboard =
  send ^c
  Clipboard = %Left%%clipboard%%Right%
  send ^v
  Clipboard := ClipSaved
  ClipSaved = 
}
```

The function works by copying the text into the clipboard, and then adding the prefix `Left` and suffix `Right` to it.

Now, I would like to add line breaks between `Left` and `clipboard` and also between `clipboard` and `Right` so that the text is wrapped between **two lines** with contents in `Left` and `Right`.  How can I do this?

I have tried adding

```
`n
```

or

```
`r
```

between the prefix and suffix and the clipboard, e.g. as follows :

```
TagWrapper(Left, Right)
{
  ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
  Clipboard =
  send ^c
  Clipboard = %Left%%`nclipboard`n%%Right%
  send ^v
  Clipboard := ClipSaved
  ClipSaved = 
}
```

but that didn't work (the script can't even run). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the middle 2 `%` characters in the following, so that they are next to the clipboard. (You seem to have inserted the ```n`` in the middle of the `%clipboard%`)

```
  Clipboard = %Left%%`nclipboard`n%%Right%
```

i.e. this would be an improvement:

```
  Clipboard = %Left%`n%clipboard%`n%Right%
```

If this still doesn't work, then there is a specific example in [the AutoHotKey Tutorial and Overview](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#Variables) that talks about using ```r`n`` to add both carriage return and linefeed.

(Depending on which platform you're on, text files will have different line endings: see [The Great Newline Schism](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html))