# AHK separate multiple lines of clipboard

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make simple AHK macro.

What I need is following:

User copies multiple lines of numbers

e.g

```
1234
12345
123125
12512
123123
```

my code needs to read from clipboard and do following action:
1234{enter}
12345{enter}
12512{enter}
12512{enter}
123123{enter}
end.

Number of lines is not set. It should depend on the size of data that is in the clipboard.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Previous answer may help  http://superuser.com/questions/342027/adding-line-breaks-to-strings-that-go-into-the-clipboard?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Did you even try to look in the **AutoHotkey.chm** help file of AutoHotkey? It can be opened from the start menu, AHK's taskbar icon menu or the directory where you installed AHK and is very helpful. If you search for "clipboard", first thing that comes up is an example how to split clipboard into lines:

```
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
    MsgBox, 4, , File number %A_Index% is %A_LoopField%.`n`nContinue?
    IfMsgBox, No, break
}
```

For your use case it must be slightly modified as follows:

```
#SingleInstance Force
+^v::
Loop, parse, clipboard, `n, `r
{
    SendRaw, %A_LoopField%
    Send {Enter}
}
return
```

You can test it in Excel, by comparing <kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

If you want the hotkey to be <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, change the second line to

```
+Insert::
```